# ReactJS: universal-cookie not being able to read cookies

Tags: reactjs, authentication, cookies

I was trying to set-up an authentication in a ReatJS + Spring-boot app. At this moment, I am able to authenticate against the server, retrieving a JWT from it. I wanted to store this token in a cookie and access it from React using the package `universal-cookie`. The code is the following:

```
login(loginRequest)
                .then(response => {
                    const cookies = new Cookies();
                    cookies.set(ACCESS_TOKEN, response.accessToken, {
                        path: '/',
                        httpOnly: false,
                        maxAge: 604800
                    });
                    console.log(cookies.get(ACCESS_TOKEN));
                    this.props.onLogin();
                })
```

After using `cookies.set()`, the cookie appears in `cookies.cookies`. Nevertheless, when I try to read it using `cookies.get()`, the cookie dissappears and prints an undefined, even though it's still present in the browser. I've already tried other packages and none seems to work.

Any idea why this might be happening?

Thanks in advance for your help.

EDIT: Some screenshots of the process:

[Before using `cookies.set`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Drr1C.png) - As you can see, the cookies array is empty.

[After using `cookies.set`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bN2qE.png) - After adding the cookie, it appears in the cookie array and in the browser.

[After using `cookies.get`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdVmw.png) - After using `cookies.get`, the array is empty again, and the `console.log` prints undefined, even though the cookie still appears in the Application tab of the browser.

Comment: The problem might be about "asynchronous" process. Can you try to call the cookie value in `setTimeout()`. As `setTimeout(() => console.log(cookies.get(ACCESS_TOKEN)), 1000)`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried it, and the result is the same, the log still prints undefined. I've added some screenshots to exemplify the problem a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

The reason of problem is related with async process exactly, you have to return the accessToken as result, and have to set/get cookie outside of callback.

Same with this, when you use cookies.get in async function, it is also not working, so you have to pass the cookie as the value of function.

```
async login(sessionValue, otherValue){
    ....
}
```